# Fedora assign date to a variable to get an integer

Tags: shell, date, if-statement, fedora

I'm new in linux environment and shell programming. Im trying to do a simple shell scripting program where I want to display "Good Morning" Good Afternoon" Good Evening" or "Good Night" according to the time in the system. I want to do this using `date` function as well. 
Below is the code I've typed to do the above task.

```
#!bin/bash 
$ say=$(date +%H)
echo "echoo  $say"
if [ "$say" -gt 18 ]
then
var="Night"
elif [ "$say" -gt 15 ]
then
var="Evening"
elif [ "$say" -gt 12 ]
then
var="Afternoon"
else
var="Morning"
fi
echo "hello $USER , $var"
```

What I planned to do here is get the hours part to a variable and check in which range that integer falls in to give the variable morning,night or whatever the value matches. 
Below is the output I get when I execute the shell script

```
time.sh: line 3: $: command not found
echoo  
time.sh: line 8: [: : integer expression expected
time.sh: line 12: [: : integer expression expected
time.sh: line 16: [: : integer expression expected
hello achala , Morning
```

Please help me through this. Thanx in advance.

Comment: The `$` at the start of that first line is an error. Remove it. That's preventing the assignment to `say` from working which means the comparison lines expand `$say` to an empty string which causes `[` to get confused.

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be: say=$(date "+%H")

Try this:

```
#!bin/bash 
say=$(date "+%H")
echo "echoo  $say"
if [ "$say" -gt 18 ]
then
var="Night"
elif [ "$say" -gt 15 ]
then
var="Evening"
elif [ "$say" -gt 12 ]
then
var="Afternoon"
else
var="Morning"
fi
echo "hello $USER , $var"
```

Comment: Care to explain what the problem was?

Comment: It worked. Thank you @GAVD Can you tell me why it should have "+%H" but not work when have +%H ?

Comment: Just see "date --help" :)